# C struct definition naming

Tags: c, struct, typedef

What is the purpose of adding the name of the `struct` after `struct` keyword, along with `type alias`?

Seems to me like the 2 definitions below would work and could be used in the exact same name, so I wonder why add the alias name twice?

```
typedef struct wifiConfig {
    char ssid[32];
    char password[64];
} wifiConfig;

typedef struct {
    char ssid[32];
    char password[64];
} wifiConfig;
```

Comment: The first is the name of the structure itself. The second is the name of the alias for the structure type.

Comment: Sometimes it will work, sometimes it will not. Try defining a linked list node. Some people always use a tag even when it would work without. It is a matter of personal stylistic preference.

Comment: As for why it might be useful, the type alias name is not defined yet when inside the structure. So if you want to reference the structure itself (like when defining node structures for a linked list) you need the structure name.

Comment: You can often dispense with structure tags, but they are needed to resolve certain forward references.  For example, if a structure contains a field whose type is a pointer to that structure, then a tag is needed.  However, the tag can be used for a typedef before the structure is defined, allowing the typedef name inside the structure definition.

Comment: Interesting, so in general would it be a good practice to always define struct type by first creating typedef struct structName structName; and then below just adding struct structName {}; ?

Comment: Don't bother with typedefs for structs. All they do is avoid having to type `struct` in a few places and they only hide the fact that something is a struct and not a scalar. Typedefing pointers to structs is an abomination. Use struct tags everywhere and you make your fellow programmer happy.

Comment: @TomKarzes I am an experienced programmer and know that other experienced programmers also recommend typedefs for structs to be avoided (e.g. Peter van der Linden of Sun Microsystems in his book "Expert C Programming").